# Adding a column to a data frame with two different variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I am sure this is a super easy answer but I am struggling with how to add a column with two different variables to my dataframe. Currently, this is what it looks like

```
   vcv.index model.index par.index grid index  estimate         se       lcl       ucl fixed
1          6           6        16    A    16 0.8856724 0.07033280 0.6650468 0.9679751      
2          7           7        17    A    17 0.6298118 0.06925471 0.4873052 0.7528014      
3          8           8        18    A    18 0.6299359 0.06658557 0.4930263 0.7487169      
4          9           9        19    A    19 0.6297988 0.05511771 0.5169948 0.7300157      
5         10          10        20    A    20 0.7575811 0.05033490 0.6461758 0.8424612      
6         21          21        61    B    61 0.8713467 0.07638687 0.6404598 0.9626184      
7         22          22        62    B    62 0.6074379 0.06881230 0.4677827 0.7314827      
8         23          23        63    B    63 0.6041054 0.06107520 0.4805279 0.7156792      
9         24          24        64    B    64 0.5806565 0.06927308 0.4422237 0.7074601      
10        25          25        65    B    65 0.7370944 0.05892108 0.6070620 0.8357394      
11        41          41       121    C   121 0.8048479 0.09684385 0.5519097 0.9324759      
12        42          42       122    C   122 0.5259547 0.07165218 0.3871380 0.6608721      
13        43          43       123    C   123 0.5427100 0.07127273 0.4033255 0.6757137      
14        44          44       124    C   124 0.5168820 0.06156392 0.3975561 0.6343132      
15        45          45       125    C   125 0.6550049 0.07378403 0.5002851 0.7826343      
16       196         196       586    A   586 0.8536314 0.08709394 0.5979992 0.9580976      
17       197         197       587    A   587 0.5672194 0.07079508 0.4268452 0.6975725      
18       198         198       588    A   588 0.5675415 0.06380445 0.4408540 0.6859714      
19       199         199       589    A   589 0.5666874 0.06499899 0.4377071 0.6872233      
20       200         200       590    A   590 0.7058542 0.05985868 0.5769484 0.8085177      
21       211         211       631    B   631 0.8360614 0.09413427 0.5703031 0.9514472      
22       212         212       632    B   632 0.5432872 0.07906200 0.3891364 0.6895701      
23       213         213       633    B   633 0.5400994 0.06497607 0.4129055 0.6622759      
24       214         214       634    B   634 0.5161692 0.06292706 0.3943257 0.6361202      
25       215         215       635    B   635 0.6821667 0.07280044 0.5263841 0.8056298      
26       226         226       676    C   676 0.7621875 0.10484478 0.5077465 0.9087471      
27       227         227       677    C   677 0.4607440 0.07326970 0.3240229 0.6036386      
28       228         228       678    C   678 0.4775168 0.08336433 0.3219349 0.6375872      
29       229         229       679    C   679 0.4517655 0.06393339 0.3319262 0.5774725      
30       230         230       680    C   680 0.5944330 0.07210672 0.4491995 0.7248303
```

then I am adding a column with periods 1-5 repeated until reaches the end
with this code

> SurJagPred$estimates %<>%    mutate(Primary  = rep(1:5, 6))
> and I also need to add sex( F, M) as well. the numbers 1-15 are female and the 16-30 are male. So overall it should look like this.

```
> vcv.index model.index par.index grid index  estimate      se       lcl       ucl fixed Primary Sex
F
1          6           6        16    A    16 0.8856724 0.07033280 0.6650468 0.9679751      1     F
2          7           7        17    A    17 0.6298118 0.06925471 0.4873052 0.7528014      2     F
3          8           8        18    A    18 0.6299359 0.06658557 0.4930263 0.7487169      3     F
4          9           9        19    A    19 0.6297988 0.05511771 0.5169948 0.7300157      4      F
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rep` with `each` on a `vector` of values to replicate each element of the vector to that many times

```
SurJagPred$estimates %<>% 
         mutate(Sex = rep(c("F", "M"), each = 15))
```